# How to verify primary key data in target table using Json source data and update with New values

Tags: sql, json, oracle

Json data

```
{ "Root":
   [
      { "Column": "Primary_key", "CurrentValue": "3456", "NewValue": null },
      { "Column": "FirstName", "CurrentValue": "Jon", "NewValue": null },
      { "Column": "Phone", "CurrentValue": "null", "NewValue": "6789" }
   ]
}
```

My Json data is from a table as shown above. I need to check if the primary key and FirstName matches a row, then update the value of column `Phone` in target row.

How to achieve this in SQL?

Comment: What is the *target*? What is your query so far?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with specifications:

```
CREATE TABLE json_table (
    <your_field_unique>,
    CONSTRAINT <unique_cond> CHECK (<your_field_unique> IS JSON WITH UNIQUE KEYS)
);
```

Into <> you can put your variables.

Regards.